# Handle error when no data to return with getElementById

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get data from a company owned webpage. I use `getElementById` method to return a value from the website.

The macro gets the data if the particular element has data else it throws an error. I tried an `On Error Resume Next` error handler method to skip the error if the particular element doesn't have any data.

```
Elementid = ctl00_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData
```

Actually its labelbox .. mostly it has data.

Code:

```vb
on error resume next

Sheets("AVS").Range("I" & lRow + 1).Value =ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData").Value
```

Comment: why not check the value of `ie.document.getelementbyid` with an `if` statement before trying to set it to a range value? eg.  `if ie.document.getelementbyid("ct100_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData").value not nothing then` ... set the value

Comment: Yeah i tried that too .. throws "object doesnt not suppert this method or property " Error

Comment: did you try it with `.value = ""`  ?

Comment: Yes tried both of your method's :( ..

Comment: The "On Error Resume Next" command ignores the error without considering what the error actually is. I recommend replacing that with an error handler that deals with individual error codes. (This probably won't fix your problem. It's just a general design suggestion).

Comment: If the element doesn't exist then you can't call any properties on it and that includes `.Value`. @scott is on the right track but you need something like `If Not ie.document.getelementbyid("ct100_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData") Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Hi barrowc , when i check that element through inspect element .. i can see     ct100_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData actually present in Source page .. Whn i debug with f8 its passes that code .. but f5 throws error ..

Comment: It occurs to me that certain HTML elements may not have a `Value` property. Try this (as three separate lines): `Dim v As Variant  Set v = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData") MsgBox TypeName(v)` Once you know the underlying object type then you can investigate which properties that type actually has

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Dim var As Variant
On Error resume Next
var = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData").Value

If Len(var) > 0 then
    Sheets("AVS").Range("I" & lRow + 1).Value = var 
Else
    'nothing in there
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub/Function 
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try setting Break in Class Module in VBE (Tool\Options\General)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I've discovered the answer.

When calling a method that returns a single DOM element (like `getElementById` or `querySelector`), you must check first that it has returned a DOM element. Do not check if it is `Nothing`. When these methods can't find the DOM element, they return the `Null` value, they do NOT return the `Nothing` object and are not objects. When they do find the DOM element, then they are objects.

This code should work:

```
If TypeName(id.Document.getElementById("ctl00_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData") = "HTMLInputElement" Then
    Sheets("AVS").Range("I" & lRow + 1).Value = ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_conMainPageContent_lblGeneralNotesData").Value
End if
```

NOTE: Methods that return more than one DOM element (e.g. `getElementsByClassName`) should be tested with `Is Nothing` since they DO return the `Nothing` object when they don't find a matching DOM element.